# I need to do some check in the UIAlertAction and avoid dismiss of the UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, swift5, uialertaction

I have an `UIAlertController` with a `TextField` and two `UIAlertAction`.
I need to check the string of the `TextField` in one of the `UIAlertAction` and prevent the dismiss of the `UIAlertController` if the string in the `TextField` doesn't match requirements

```
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { alert -> Void in
    let titleTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField

    //Prevent dismiss if text in textField doesn't match requirements

})
```

I already tried something like :

```swift
(alertController.actions[1] as UIAlertAction).isEnabled = false
```

But it's already too late for this in the `UIAlertAction`

So is there any way to prevent dismiss while already in the handle of the `UIAlertAction` ?

Comment: I don't think so, i need to do a check on the click of the button and not just disable the button to avoid the action

Comment: Maybe a `UIAlertController` isn't the right UI for this task.

Comment: The anwser "It's not possible" is also acceptable, but i want to be sure i didn't miss something

Comment: @MathieuRobert It is not possible currently. Alert will be dismissed once you tap the button. The only way to tackle this is through UITextFieldDelegate methods and enable/disable the button based on that.

Comment: @PGDev Ok thanks, know i'm sure i need to do what i want in another way ^^

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to stop dismiss in UIAlertAction you can set UITextField delegate in,

```
func addTextField(configurationHandler: ((UITextField) -> Void)? = nil)
```

method and use the delegate call,

```
optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

to enable and disable the UIAlertAction.

Comment: I need to have the button clickable at least once to show a message to the user depending on what he put in the TextField